# Android Studio (MAC OS) "IDE to be running Java 1.8 or later [...] install a supported JDK"

Tags: java, android, macos, installation

I'm trying to setup Android Studio. However i can't fix this problem with my "preview" called the "Rendering Problem" (see the pictures that i've added for more info). I'm pretty new (this is my first android app) to codeing and computing, but i would like som help figuring this out, since i can't find anything on the internet myself. If its to any help, i'm using the latest update - both Mac OS and Android Studio. 
I have added a picture of my "default project structure" for the SDK Location, i think i've done something wrong here.

I've also installed the latest version of Java JRE and JDK, i i'm 98% sure that i have set it up in the right way. 
Thanks for your time.

My Java Path is the following: Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk

[The picture that i've mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbiBx.png)

[default project structure" for the SDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2gKH.png)

Comment: Have you tried http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location and set the JDK path in your android studio, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've changed my question after trying to take a look at your answer. I didn't change anything since i don't understand what is wrong with my path for the SDK and JDK. Would you mind taking a quick look at my settings show in the picture?

Comment: Can you go to  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/  in your Mac and check what is the jdk version installed there ?

Comment: The version is 1.8.0_101